# Mysql - updating and insert using select * using a target column

Tags: mysql

```
update table1 t1
inner join
table2 t2 on
t1.a = t2.a
set t1.b = t2.b,
t1.c = t2.c;
```

This code works to join 2 tables on column a.  My problem is that I have about 500 columns which I want to update and am currently writing out each of the 500 columns in the code up to

```
t1.500 = t2.500;
```

This works, but it is slow and inefficient.  Does anyone know how you can select * from table2 to update table1, keeping the join on t1.a = t2.a?  All of the column names match exactly and am inserting all of the columns from table2.  Was thinking of something like this below although I know that this is not correct.  Thank you!

```
update table1 t1
inner join
table2 t2 on
t1.a = t2.a
set t1.* = t2.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to make update query with a wildcard in mysql. Don't know if it will properly fit to your problem, but you can try this workaround. :

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id IN (<ids>);
```

Delete all the records from table2 that are satisfying given condition. And then insert the corresponding records from table1 to table2.

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (<ids>);
```

Comment: Thanks, Krasipenkov.  Its

Comment: Its an interesting solution, but I think it will be too bulky and I lose the ability to join the tables on column a.  Think I will just stick with the long way unless there is another workaround available.  Thank you